# What happens when the left side of a row in a matrix = x but the right side = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let's say the row = [ 0 0 1 0]

I'm new to all of this and this it looks odd that the variable z would be equal to zero.

Comment: this is a row of an augmented matrix for a system in x,y, and z @littleO

Comment: @SakethMalyala Thanks, I deleted my comment since you were able to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

We have that $0x+0y+1z=0$

Therefore, $1z=0$, and $z=0$.

That can happen.

Comment: i see, but what type of solution would a matrix that contains this row have?

Comment: It depends on the other rows. Any matrix that has this row has z=0, unless the matrix has no solution @Sean D

Comment: that answers a lot, thank you so much!